# Is it possible to get file path (not application path) from process ID using python?

Tags: python, path, pid, psutil

I have a file saved to desktop. I can get the process ID of the file using the python code below. However, in my case, there user might need to select a particular application instance from a list of open instances, so I need to display the file path of all the instances of my app. Is there a way I can obtain the file path of the application using python?

I used `psutil` to get PID corresponding to a given application. Here the notepad file is saved to `C:/Users/username/Desktop/`. The code is given below

```py
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "Notepad.exe":
        print(f"Process ID: {proc.pid} => Application: {proc.name()} => Path: {proc.exe()}")
```

This gives me an output of

```
Process ID: 20188 => Application: Notepad.exe => Path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_11.2311.35.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Notepad\Notepad.exe
```

I also tried `sys.argv`, but it doesn't output the result I am looking for.

Is there a way to get file location instead of application path using python?
Thank you.

Comment: Unsure exactly what you're asking, but does `os.getcwd()` solve your problem?

Comment: What do you hope "the process ID of the file" should mean?

Comment: I have a CAD tool that have can two instances open at the same time. One instance can have a PID of 345 and the other PID=789. It will be difficult for end user to recognize which instance they want to work with from PID. Instead having the file path helps. The GUI will show open instances of the CAD tool with file paths and the user then connects to the relevant instance for further work.

Comment: Unless you run the program from the command prompt with something like `notepad.exe filename`, the file isn't in `sys.argv`. Double clicking on the file, or loading it in from a file selector, doesn't put it in argv.